# iOS: Navigate to certain row after didReceiveLocalNotification in SplitViewController (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

Could someone please help give me some pointers on how to tackle this situation:

My application is a fairly straight forward Master Detail application using a UISplitViewController.

I've setup UILocalNotification and create each one with a userInfo containing a reference.

When I get the notification and swipe it takes me to back into the app and I can see the userInfo in didReceiveLocalNotification.

My question is how do I now use that information to take the user straight to that particular Item in the Detail View Controller?

Say the Detail View Controller is already open with another Item loaded, I can't seem to get popToRootViewController to work.

This is my first time working with UISplitViewControllers and it's giving me some headaches.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Should add uisplitviewcontroller tag as well

Answer (score 0):

There should be a segue setup from Master to Detail. Then you need to call `performSegueWithIdentifier` from  `didReceiveLocalNotification` which will open Detail View. Set correct UserInfo in `prepareForSegue` method which will be called before Detail View opens. You may check out a simple [Master Detail Sample](http://swiftwala.com/multiple-detail-views) done by me.